# Out of multiple lists, how do I find and return the list that contains the value I want?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = [9,10,11,12]
```

If I want to search for 6, the code should return b

Similarly

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 7]]
```

If I want to search for [2,5], the code should return 0 and 2 because the elements 2 and 5 are in a[0] and a[2] respectively.

This is what I have done so far.

```
x = []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
x.append(c)
print(x)
Output:[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

If I want to search for 5, the following code will return the index of 5. I want to know if there is a better way to solve this & want to know how to solve the second part.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if(5 in x[i]):
        print(i)
    else:
        continue
Output:1
```

Comment: use `np.argwhere` before that make it numpy array. `np.argwhere(a == 5)[0][0]`

Comment: also tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: that's a good start, please paste in any errors you're receiving so we can help

Comment: The question got downvoted by me because I didn't see any effort from your side. Since you have mentioned your approach I am taking back the downvote. +1

Comment: @Roman : you can use numpy. I have updated the answer for both of the question.

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helps. If you are working on the array data. You can use numpy :). Also next time when posting the question. Do mention your effort and where you are stuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 1st part:

```
a = [1,2,3,8]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = [9,10,11,12]

l = np.array(list(zip(a,b,c))).T

res = np.where(np.isin(l, [2,5]))[0]
```

---

**l:**

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

**res:**

```
array([0, 1])
```

---

for 2nd part:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 7]]

res = np.where(np.isin(a, [2,5,1]))[0]
```

---

**res:**

```
array([0, 0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I believe this should give the correct output

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 7]]
y = [2,5]
for i in y:
    for c, j in enumerate(x):
        for k in j:
            if i == k:
                print(c)
```

It basically traverses the each list in `x` to find the values in `y` list.